# static uint8_t variable changes to incorrect value when using += on Mac

Tags: c, static-variables

I had a colleague today ask me a question regarding his code that I could not answer. He is writing a C unit test on Mac that makes use of a static uint8_t variable (initialized to 0) for holding the current read position from a test buffer across invocations of a seemingly simple read function in the test code. The arithmetic was as follows:

```
    /*Fails to add correctly on the third iteration of the loop \*/
    /* static uint8_t currentReadPosition = 0; \*/
    /* uint32_t tempreadamount \*/
    currentReadPosition += tempreadamount;
```

I ran the code on Linux, and the values changed correctly ( according to the code ), so the issue seems to be specific to the Mac platform. I requested he change the value from uint8_t to uint32_t on a hunch and when he re-ran the test, it ran correctly.

```
    /* Works correctly \*/
    /* static uint32_t currentReadPosition \*/
    /* uint32_t tempreadamount \*/
    currentReadPosition += tempreadamount;
```

He is using memcpy() in the function, but the write destination is outside the scope of the function ( it is passed into the read function as a parameter ). I didn't see any issues with him using a wrong destination pointer or anything.

I have no idea why uint32_t works and uint8_t doesn't on Mac, but uint8_t will work fine on Linux. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Thank you.

```
uint8_t resetcurrptr = 0;
int readfunc_cb_test( uint8_t* OutBuf, uint32_t NumBytes )
{
static uint8_t currentReadPosition = 0;

  if( resetcurrptr )
  {
    currentReadPosition = 0;
  }

  uint32_t readamt = NumBytes;
  if( NumBytes > ( ( sizeof(TestRequestPacket) / sizeof(TestRequestPacket[0] ) ) - currentReadPosition) )
  {
    readamt = ( sizeof(TestRequestPacket) / sizeof(TestRequestPacket[0]) - currentReadPosition );
  }

  memcpy( OutBuf, &TestRequestPacket[currentReadPosition], readamt );

  currentReadPosition += readamt;

  return readamt;
}
```

Comment: If `TestRequestPacket` (not shown) is a pointer, then `sizeof(TestRequestPacket)` will give different results on different platforms. And so `readamt` the value you add will too.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

So, I solved the mystery this morning...

My colleague is using LLDB for debugging on Mac instead of GDB. When he debugs this with LLDB and the value reaches 8, the debugger shows '\b'. It turns out that this is not 0xB, but rather '\b'...the ASCII code for BACKSPACE, which has an integer value of 8.

I only figured this out after seeing the behavior again when we were looking into by his struct was (seemingly) padding out to 11 when it should have had no padding at all..

Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a uint32 to a uint8 can lead to overflow (the 8 bits wrap around and start from 0 again if the result is more than 255). If overflow is happening in your case then that could be the explanation.

From http://www.cs.utah.edu/~regehr/papers/overflow12.pdf: "Many unsigned integer overflows in C and C++ are welldefined, but non-portable"

So, the change you mention on currentReadPosition to be uint32 is the right solution. It makes the code more portable and is in general good practice to avoid overflows unless necessary.

Comment: Your quote is in relation to: *"...UINT_MAX, but the actual value of that constant is implementation defined"* which is true, but in this case the type is `uint8_t` and its maximum value is always `255`.